# How do I retrieve the custom type of a typescript variable at runtime

Tags: typescript, types, typeof

I am defining a custom type "Identifier" and creating a variable of this type but I can't get the type of this variable at runtime

```
type Identifier = number;

let myNumber: number;
let myIdentifier: Identifier;

console.log(`myNumber is a ${typeof myNumber}`);
console.log(`myIdentifier is a ${typeof myIdentifier}`);

myNumber = 1234;
myIdentifier = 1234;

console.log(`myNumber is a ${typeof myNumber}`);
console.log(`myIdentifier is a ${typeof myIdentifier}`);
```

When I run the code above I get the following results in the console

myNumber is a undefined

myIdentifier is a undefined

myNumber is a number

myIdentifier is a number

My first problem is that I get an undefined when the variable does not have a value.

My second problem is that when I assign a value to myIdentifier, the type is a number and not an Identifer.

The reason I'm doing this is to distinguish an Identifier as a special type for special processing later on.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because typescript is compiled into JavaScript and Javascript is not static typing, so at run time, you will not know the type of the variable, only know the type of the value that variable is holding. That is the reason you see 'undefined' instead of 'number'. Also, there is no concept of 'Identifier' in javascript (already stripped away when you compile to javascript), hence, you see 'number' not 'Identifier'.
2. Even on other programming language, when you define a type alias like you did, it only helps during the compile time, not run time. So you only see number, not Identifier.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to achieve my objective differently?

Comment: You can define a class `Identifier` and put value as a property. Then check by `variable.constructor.name` == `Identifier`. But remember to initialize the variable to default value instead of `undefined`

Comment: if I try the following code

class Identifier {
    constructor(public value:number) {}
}
let myIdentifier: Identifier;
console.log(`myIdentifier is a ${typeof myIdentifier}`);

myIdentifier = new Identifier(1234);
console.log(`myIdentifier is a ${typeof myIdentifier}`);

I get the following results

myIdentifier is a object
myIdentifier is a undefined

Comment: typeof myIdentifier is 'object', you need to check myIdentifier.constructor.name